# Simple url rewrite in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

How do I redirect:

```
/text1 to /
```

and

```
/test2 to /something/else
```

I tried putting:

```
rewrite ^ /test1 /
rewrite ^ /test2 /something/else
```

Inside the server {}

Comment: What sort of redirect?  Do you want it to match subpaths?  If so, what do you want to do with them (discard or preserve)?

Comment: there are not going to be any subpaths, exact matches only. Just very simple redirection. if /test1 then goto / or if /test2 go to /thispath. Actually examples with subpaths preserved and discarded would be nice to (for me to learn by example)

Comment: But what do you mean by "go to"?

Comment: someone types in site.com/test1, server sends redirect header and redirects them to / .

Comment: What response code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of the space after the `^`, and add the required `;`:

```
rewrite ^/test1$ /;
rewrite ^/test2$ /something/else;
```

The `$` characters denote the end of the string.  Get rid of them if you want `/test1/blah` to match as well as `/test1`.

***Edit:*** To send a redirect response to the browser add either `redirect` (for a 302 response) or `permanent` (for a 301 response) as a flag to your `rewrite` lines:

```
rewrite ^/test1$ / permanent;
rewrite ^/test2$ /something/else permanent;
```

Comment: Should these go into a specific location {} or just simply under server {} ?

Comment: They work in either context.  And I have the same clarifying question as womble - are you looking to have this send a redirection response to the user so that the URL in their address bar changes, or keep `/test2` in their address bar but serve the content from `/something/else`?

Comment: Yes, I would like the url in browser to change to / and /somethingelse respectively

Comment: @user80666 See edit.

Comment: That works thank you. One problem I noticed however, is that if I change the redirection url and restart the server browser still remembers the old redirection address, almost like it's cached. Is there anything I can do to prevent browsers cacheing the redirection url?

Comment: @user80666 The 301 response code from the `permanent` flag is cached by some browsers.  If the redirects will always be there, then you'll want to leave it like that; if not, change the flag from `permanent` to simply `redirect` to send a 302.